# JavaScript returning new Promise without resolve() statement, doesn't await as expected

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I have a very simple code snippet like this

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    console.log("This promise will never resolve");
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("START");
    // neverResolve().then().catch(); // uncommenting this line works as expected
    await neverResolve();
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));
    console.log("END");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR: ", error);
  }
})();
```

Why the above function doesn't wait for 5 second and print's the `END`.
It automatically terminates after printing

```
START
This promise will never resolve
```

But if we execute the same function but with a `.then()` construct, I get the expected result.

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    console.log("This promise will never resolve");
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("START");
    neverResolve().then().catch(); 
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));
    console.log("END");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR: ", error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Try removing the `async` keyword in front of the definition of `neverResolves`. Otherwise you're wrapping it in two promises, which is not what you meant to do.

Comment: `neverResolve().then().catch();` doesn't wait. It's a fire and forget. Therefore, the code will continue past it. The first one never resolves and eventually the process is killed. No real reason to keep it around forever.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie doesn't really matter. With `async function` the promise from `neverResolves()` will assume the state of the promise returned. So, it's just the same non-resolving promise at the end.

Comment: I add some general advice: `async/await` is just syntactical sugar. When you are experiencing a different behavior in a code that is just syntactical sugar, you can just paste it in BabelJS and see how it gets converted

Comment: `await new Promise(() => {});` is evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's happening in your case:

1. Your program starts it's execution from an anonymous IIFE async function, as this is an async function, it immediately returns a Promise to a global scope.So the execution of anonymous IIFE is deferred .
   You can easily validate this by adding a `console.log("OK");` at the end of your IIFE invocation, which is printed to the console
2. *Node keeps a reference count of things like timers and network requests. When you make a network, or other async request, set a timer, etc. Node adds on to this ref count. When the times/request resolve Node subtracts from the count. [Ref. video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w)*
   So what happens inside your IIFE is:

   - `console.log("START");` <--- gets printed to console
   - `await neverResolve();` Here things get's interesting, this `await` call will defer the execution and blocks until the callback are executed, either `resolve` or `reject`.

   But in this case there are no callbacks registered and nodejs will think that it finished processing all the request and will terminate the process.

Comment: It makes sense after watching the video link you posted and the explanation was to the point.

Answer (score 1):

`neverResolve` neither resolves or rejects, so the program hangs indefinitely at the `await`. Consider abstracting the timeout functionality in its own generic function, `timeout` -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

const timeout = (p, ms) =>
  Promise.race([
    p,
    sleep(ms).then(() => { throw Error("timeout") })
  ]);
  
const neverResolve = () => new Promise(() => {});

(async function() {
  try {
    console.log("connecting...");
    await timeout(neverResolve(), 2000);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example `await neverResolve();` waits forever and never resolves as stated. Javascript can go off and do other things in other tasks while waiting for this.

In the second example by adding `.then()` you've told javascript to continue processing code below. Typically, all the code below would either be inside the callback for `then()` or `catch()` which would then create the same pause you're seeing.

There are very deliberate reasons for these nuances that allow you to send a fetch request, do other work and then come back to see if the fetch is done later. See my comments in this marked up and slightly modified example.

```
async function slowFetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // a fetch statement that takes forever
    fetch().then(data => resolve(data));
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("START");

    // start the slow fetch right away
    const dataPromise = slowFetch();

    // do some other tasks that don't take as long
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));

    // wait for the data to arrive
    const data = await dataPromise;

    // do something with the data like fill in the page.

    console.log("END");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR: ", error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: The OP is  asking about why returning a Promise that never calls `resolve()` doesn't executes the code block after await it, but in your example, you are doing a `resolve() inside a `slowFetch()``

Comment: `new Promise((resolve) => {  fetch().then(data => resolve(data));});` is an exceptionally bad example as it just encourages the pointless *and dangerous* [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743). The one in this code never handles the rejected promise of `fetch()` thus runs a real risk of becoming unresolvable.

Comment: Yes, I answer that in my first sentence, then contrast it with how the second examples works and continues processing. Finally I tried to pull together an example of why you would potentially not immediately await a promise which straddles both both examples and the original question.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `neverResolve().then().catch();` what you actually did is;

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    console.log("This promise will never resolve");
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("START");
    (async function(){
       try {
         await neverResolve()
       }
       catch{
       }
     })(); 
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000));
    console.log("END");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERR: ", error);
  }
})();
```

The inner async IIFE runs just like `neverResolve().then().catch();` does. You should not mix promises with `async await` abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the above function doesn't wait for 5 second and print's the END. It automatically terminates after printing

Because your code never gets past this:

```
await neverResolve();
```

Since `neverResolve()` returns a promise that never resolves or rejects, this function is forever suspended at that line and the lines of code after this statement in the function never execute.

`await` means that the function execution should be suspended indefinitely until the promise you are awaiting either resolves or rejects.

---

> But if we execute the same function but with a .then() construct, I get the expected result.

When you change the `await` to this:

```
neverResolve().then().catch();
```

The function execute is NOT suspended at all.  It executes `neverResolve()`.  That returns a promise which it then calls `.then()` on.  That call to `.then()` just registers a callback with the promise (to be called later when the promise resolves).  That returns another promise which it then calls `.catch()` on which just registers a callback with the promise (to be called later if/when the promise rejects).

Now, you aren't even passing a callback in either case, so those `.then()` and `.catch()` have nothing to actually do, but even if you did pass a callback to each of them, then they would just register that callback and immediately return.  `.then()` and `.catch()` are not blocking.  They just register a callback and immediately return.  So, after they return, then next lines of code in the function will execute and you will get the output you were expecting.

---

**Summary**

`await` suspends execution of the function until the promise you are awaiting resolves or rejects.

`.then()` and `.catch()` just register callbacks for some future promise state change.  They do not block.  They do not suspend execution of the function.  They register a callback and immediately return.